# Remove the left font lock of flyspell after uncomment

Tags: font-lock, flyspell, ispell

I use `flyspell-prog-mode`, and quite often I comment a region, the source code was checked, and the font lock of dirty words will left after I uncomment the source code.

[image]
[image]
[image]
How can I fixes this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you basically just want to remove flyspell overlays from the beginning of the region with `start` at the beginning of `require_columns` and `end` at the last closing `}`?  So we just take `uncomment-region` and use the same `start`/`end` to remove flyspell overlays within that region, right?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to advice `uncomment-region` to call `flyspell-region` after it's done?

Comment: @omajid -- you are on the right track, but you just need `flyspell-delete-region-overlays` with the correct `start`/`end`.  Go ahead and write it up and collect your 100 points.  :)  My understanding is that the original poster wants zero flyspell overlays when the uncommenting process is concluded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've also found the function `flyspell-delete-region-overlays` but tracking disabling `flyspell-mode` which deletes the overlays automatically. By advising `uncomment-region` I solved this but I'm  glad to accept the answer from anyone other than me:)

Comment: I'm just speculating here, but maybe you can inject something into the font-lock system that would clear flychecks overlays whenever part of a buffer is rehighlighted. Technically, you could add a font-lock keyword that would perform the clear as a side effect, while always failing to match anything (i.e. it should return nil). (Should anybody want to try it out and if it works, feel free to post it as an answer.)